# Twitter API 1.1 PHP - POST with rawurlencode()

Tags: php, post, twitter, urlencode

Fairly new to the Twitter API and I'm having a problem posting to Twitter through API 1.1 using rawurlencode(). When I tweet an apostrophe, just normally) it tweets as a HTML entity, the docs say to use urlencode to remove HTML entities.

```
$vinedesc = rawurlencode('Cameron doesn\'t like the Walmart playground prices... ');

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $vinedesc));
```

That outputs the following as a tweet, inclusive of the percentage encoding:

> Cameron%20doesn%27t%20like%20the%20Walmart%20playground%20prices...%20

How do I get this to tweet as:

> Cameron doesn't like the Walmart playground prices...

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the **`URLdecode`** function. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: Actually, I was using urlencode to remove HTML entities from the tweets after I POST. Using decode would just submit the normal UTF 8 encoded text and result in HTML entities appearing in my tweets again.

Comment: While posting use your `urlencode` , and whilst retrieving/displaying the posted content make use of `urldecode`.